# Pytest: Patching upon import

Tags: python, pytest, monkeypatching

I have a file as such

`db.py`:

```
DB = DBObject()

def some_func():
    return 'some stuff'
```

In my test file, I am trying to test some_func but it fails because the DBObject gets initialized on import.

```
from db import some_func

def test_some_func():
    asset some_func() == 'some stuff'
```

Is there a way to patch the DBObject on import?

Comment: Does your `some_func` is consuming the DB variable or calls one of its method ? Like do you want to patch a specific method of DB ?

Comment: `some_func` doesn't use the DB variable, but other functions in that file do. I just need it to not fail when it's imported.